# How to set input date from ajax laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, date

I have a date form that I want to fill in the value of ajax response, on the server side I use laravel and the data form becomes like this `2020-02-18` i try with this code, but it doesn't work. How do I fix it?

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{route('santri-edit-perijinan')}}" + "?id=" + id + "&type=" + type,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.mulai_ijin);
        $("#tanggal_ijin").val(data.mulai_ijin);
    }
}); 
and this my html
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tanggal_ijin" name="tanggal">
```

Comment: Which format you want to fill the date input ?

Comment: give `new Date(data.mulai_ijin)` a go. If you need it formatted differently use the format options.

Comment: @AmalSR dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @MichaelMano and how i change that format to be dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Return the format in which you want the date from Laravel controller code itself

Comment: So convert the date from 2020-02-18 to 18/02/2020 in your controller using Carbon or simple date()

Comment: yes thank you all, it's done now

Comment: @Newbie1123 In your ajax success you can directly use 
var date = data.mulai_ijin
var newdate = date.split("-").reverse().join("/");
$("#tanggal_ijin").val(data.mulai_ijin);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML input `type=date` accept `yyyy-MM-dd` format as input, So as long as your backend returns the date in the said format, your `.val()` function won't have any issue in setting the date.
If your date is being converted in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format as per PHP formats, you should convert the format using carbon.
`Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');`

PHP date format `Y-m-d` is equivalent to `yyyy-MM-dd` format.